# php check regex with variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a variable contains a string:

```
$var = "hello"
if($key == '/*/' + $var '/*/')
```

now $key can contains "good_hello" and "not_hello1" things like that.
i want it to catch only $key that has "hello" in them.

i also tried:

```
if(preg_match('/*/' + $var '/*/', $key)
```

and it was acting the same catching weird words that dont contains the word "* hello *"
means anything hello anything (couldnt do it properly by typing regular)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to my problem:

```
if(strpos($key, $var) !== false)
```

i hope it will help others who needs.